# Audio Streaming Application in Python/Django Web Framework on AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, audio

```html
This is a part of my view:
songs_lastfour = Song.objects.all().order_by('uploaded_at').reverse()[:4]

This is how I handle it in HTML
{% for song in songs_lastfour %}
     <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
         <div class="item r" data-id="item-{{ song.id }}" data-src="{{ song.song_file.url }}">
            <div class="item-media ">
              <a href="{% url 'home:track_detail'%}" class="item-media-content" style="background-image: url('{% static 'account/images/b0.jpg'%}')";></a>
              <div class="item-overlay center">
                <button  class="btn-playpause">Play</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
              <div class="item-overlay bottom text-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn-favorite"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn-more" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu pull-right black lt"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item-title text-ellipsis">
                <a href="{% url 'home:track_detail'%}">{{song.song_name}}</a>
              </div>
              <div class="item-author text-sm text-ellipsis ">
                <a href="artist.detail.html" class="text-muted">{{song.artist}}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
{% endfor %}
```

My Application allows me to upload songs from computer and it works fine when I play my tracks for a certain period of time even from different devices. However, songs stop working when I upload more songs or play old uploaded ones.

On AWS, the error_log for example says [Tue Sep 19 09:07:08.992382 2017] [:error] [pid 4962] Not Found: /media/3/Clean Bandit - Rockabye ft. Sean Paul & Anne-Marie Official Video.mp3

On the browser like Chrome, I get this error DOMException: The element has no supported sources.

Although, I can see the name of the artist, song name and the length of the song, but it doesn't work giving this error (Oh Snap, there was a playback error!)from the JS file. player.js

Anyone had the same issue before?

Comment: It would help to include the relevant code for how the uploads are handled, and how the play list is generated/updated.

Comment: Hi Brennan, I edited the issue to include some code of my view and HTML. Thank you